# Same IDs with different _routing values

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

According to elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#_unique_ids_with_custom_routing), it is possible to have docs with the same _id indexed with different _routing values. Hence, the documentation states that the uniqueness on _id is not guaranteed because these docs can end up on different shards (which appears to be a feature rather than a bug)

How about the scenario when two docs with the same _id indexed with different routing values end up on the same shard? Consider the query body below:

```
PUT test-index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": 
    {
      "number_of_shards": 2
      }
  }
}


PUT test-index/_doc/1?routing=user1
{
  "title": "This is document number with routing=user1"
}

PUT test-index/_doc/1?routing=user2
{
  "title": "This is document number with routing=user2"
}

GET test-index/_search
```

The search queries renders the following result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "user2",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is document number with routing=user2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why does the search response only shows doc under user2 despite having 2 shards? It is certain that both docs ended up on the same shard because as per formula:

```
shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor
where routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards
```

In my case routing_factor is 1 (i.e. 2 routing shards / 2 primary shards), so the shard ID is basically the hash of the _routing value mod 2.

Using your routing values, we get the following shard IDs (we can experiment murmur3 [here](http://murmurhash.shorelabs.com/)):

```
murmur3("user1") % 2 = 3305849917 % 2 = shard 1
murmur3("user2") % 2 = 4180509323 % 2 = shard 1
```

However, if both docs with same _id containing different _routing values end up on the same shard, why does it only show one doc?

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr

Because they share the same ID on the same shard, the second query is not an `insert`, it is an update.

## Evidences:

If you play the following commands in order:

```json
PUT 76349386
{
  "settings": {
    "index": 
    {
      "number_of_shards": 2
      }
  }
}
```

Then

```json
PUT 76349386/_doc/1?routing=user1
{
  "title": "This is document number with routing=user1"
}
```

Will give you:

```json
{
  "_index": "76349386",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",  <= Here it says the result of the operation was a creation
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

But then when you will play the second command

```json
PUT 76349386/_doc/1?routing=user2
{
  "title": "This is document number with routing=user2"
}
```

The response will look a little bit different:

```json
{
  "_index": "76349386",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 2,
  "result": "updated", <= it is an update.
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 1,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

The document with `_id` 1 has been updated.

Comment: I am glad I could clear that up.